# My dropdown list option is changing to previous position on submit button in php

Tags: php, html, select

Here I have two select box,one for month and other for year,for month it is working but for year in my case its coming based on current year dynamically.In the case of year when I select any option and click submit button,the option is changing and going to previous position again.Can anyone help me please. here is the code

### HTML & PHP

```
<form action="" method="post" id="nameform">
  <select name="fetchmonth">
<option <?php if ($_POST['fetchmonth'] == 'January') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >January</option>
<option <?php if ($_POST['fetchmonth'] == 'February') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>February</option>
    <option <?php if ($_POST['fetchmonth'] == 'March') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>March</option>
</select>
<select class="boottext" name="fetchyear" required id="month" >
    <?php
 $expenses_year = date('Y');
// populate the select options with years
for ($yr = date("Y"); $yr >= 1970; $yr--) {
    if ($yr == $expenses_year) {
        echo '<option value="' . $yr . '" selected="selected">' . $yr .
            '</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="' . $yr . '">' . $yr . '</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<button type="submit" form="nameform" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: The right syntax is : <option value="myValue" selected>. Documentation here : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: $yr == $expenses_year == date("Y") it never change. Where is the year wanted ?

Comment: I think you want : $expenses_year = $_POST['fetchyear'];

Comment: I think you can mark this post as closed.

Comment: Thanks its working fine

Comment: Rather post an answer, and mark it as correct. At least that way the question doesn't remain open.

Comment: I am not getting any check mark option here to mark as correct